# Tess two and tessdata folder

Tags: java, android, ocr, tesseract, tess-two

I am developing an Android ocr app with the tess-two library.
While testing I manually copied the tessdata folder in my test device but now I need a programmatically way to do it.
How the other apps do? Is it necessary to copy the folder or can I do in other ways?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do this programmatically. I would advice you give you android app Permission to access the phones memory so that you can copy this data on load.

here is a sample code I used for a project

protected static final String PHOTO_TAKEN = "photo_taken";

path = DATA_PATH  + "ocr.jpg";

```
    String[] paths = new String[] { DATA_PATH, DATA_PATH + "tessdata/" };
    for (String path : paths) {
        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "ERROR: Creation of directory " + path + " on sdcard failed");
                return;
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Created directory " + path + " on sdcard");
            }
        }

    }
```